# RegEx check how many characters are surrounded by whitespace characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

There are strings to be processed by a function, and the whole process looks like:

```py
surrounding_characters = ["\n", "\t", "\r"]
input_string = "\nT\t \tE\t\nS\n\rT\t"
_s = "".join(surrounding_characters)

pattern = re.compile(rf"([\s\S])(?<=[{_s}])(?=[{_s}])")

print(re.findall(pattern, input_string))
## ['\t', '\n']
```

I rather expected to see `['T', ' ', 'E', 'S', 'T']` as an output, because each of these characters is surrounded by whitespace characters. Removing the first group from the pattern and leaving it as `[\s\S]` doesn't change behavior of the method either.

How to make it work as expected?

Comment: Look, `([\s\S])(?<=[\r\t\n])` means *any char that is equal to CR, LF or TAB*. It only matches these three chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `[\s\S]` at wrong place. It should be placed between lookbehind and lookahead assertions:

```sh
>>> surrounding_characters = ["\n", "\t", "\r"]
>>> input_string = "\nT\t \tE\t\nS\n\rT\t"
>>> _s = "".join(surrounding_characters)
>>> pattern = re.compile(rf"(?<=[{_s}])[\s\S](?=[{_s}])")
>>> print (re.findall(pattern, input_string))
['T', ' ', 'E', 'S', 'T']
```

Note that you can also use single line modifier `(?s)` here with `.`:

```sh
>>> pattern = re.compile(rf"(?s)(?<=[{_s}]).(?=[{_s}])")
```

When you place `.` or `[\s\S]` in between lookbehind and lookahead condition, regex engine applies those conditions at right position.